# ORACLE SQL Keep Data Show Even On Another Table Column Parameter Not Existed

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display data with another table with parameter `DESCRIPTIONID`.

Now I want to keep data shown even on another table is null/empty(not existed DESCRIPTIONID).

Below query work if both table have an `DESCRIPTIONID`.

```
SELECT D.DESCRIPTIONID, D.DESCRIPTION, D.PROFILEID_FK, D.ACTIVE, P.PROFILEID, P.PROFILE_NAME FROM WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D, WA_BT_TBL_PROFILE P WHERE D.PROFILEID_FK = P.PROFILEID AND D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0001' AND D.ACTIVE = 'Y' ORDER BY D.DATEADDED ASC
```

And here the query I want to improve:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
D.DESCRIPTIONID,
D.DESCRIPTION,
Y.TIME
FROM
WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D,
WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y
WHERE
D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK AND
D.PROFILEID_FK = Y.PROFILEID_FK AND
D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0001'
ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC
```

Let's see on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e63c/1)

Please try both query on SQL Fiddle.
As you can see I want "Break Time II" keep show.

Finally I want the query show like below:

```
DESCRIPTIONID   DESCRIPTION          TIME
DS0003          Break Time I         10:00
DS0001          Operator Clock Time  15:30
DS0002          Working Time I       17:00
DS0024          Break Time II             <-- keep show this row(null/empty)
```

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Hint!)

Comment: @jarlh Please advice Sir how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outer join.

In the older and harder to understand syntax (the one you used), like this (note the `(+)` on the conditions):

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
  D.DESCRIPTIONID,
  D.DESCRIPTION,
  Y.TIME
FROM
  WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D,
  WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y
WHERE
  D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK(+) AND
  D.PROFILEID_FK = Y.PROFILEID_FK(+) AND
  D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0001'
ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC
```

In the more encouraged one (explicitly writing `LEFT JOIN...ON`):

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  D.DESCRIPTIONID,
  D.DESCRIPTION,
  Y.TIME
FROM
  WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D LEFT JOIN
  WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y ON D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK AND
  D.PROFILEID_FK = Y.PROFILEID_FK AND
  D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0001'

ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use explicit joins - they are easier to read and understand

Comment: Remove that ancient `(+)` query. It shouldn't be encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Few things, don't you the old style `JOIN` they are very outdated, You will need to just a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The `WHERE` clause on your query is limiting the return to results that exists in both tables :

```
WHERE
D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
```

This is essentially an `INNER JOIN`.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  D.DESCRIPTIONID, 
  D.DESCRIPTION,
  Y.TIME
FROM 
WA_BT_TBL_DESCRIPTION D
LEFT OUTER JOIN WA_BT_TBL_DAY Y ON D.DESCRIPTIONID = Y.DESCRIPTIONID_FK
WHERE
D.PROFILEID_FK = 'PF0001'
ORDER BY Y.TIME ASC
```

There is a post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/8086878) which explains the different types of joins really well

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Noted it