# Can I use Keyless Entity Types to query CHANGETABLE in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, change-tracking

I'm using SQL Server Change Tracking and I'm trying to adapt this article from Microsoft Docs to an Entity Framework application: [Work with Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server).

I want to run this SQL query using Entity Framework:

```
SELECT
    P.*, CT.*
FROM
    dbo.Product AS P
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Product, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT
ON
    P.ProductID = CT.ProductID
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    // omitted dozens of other properties
}

public class ProductChange
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public Product? Product { get; set; }

    public long SYS_CHANGE_VERSION { get; set; }

    public long? SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION { get; set; }

    public char SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION { get; set; }

    public byte[]? SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS { get; set; }

    public byte[]? SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT { get; set; }
}
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProductChange>()
        .HasNoKey()
        .ToView(null);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

```
long lastSynchronizationVersion = ...; // obtained as described in "Work with Change Tracking"

const string sql = @"
    SELECT
        P.*, CT.*
    FROM
        dbo.Product AS P
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Product, {0}) AS CT
    ON
        P.ProductID = CT.ProductID";

var changes = await dbContext.Set<ProductChange>.FromSqlRaw(sql, lastSynchronizationVersion);
```

It does not work, because EF does not understand how `P.*` maps to `public Product? Product { get; set; }`. When I remove the `Product` property and remove `P.*` from the query, things work as expected. However, I need all of the properties, not just the ID.

**Copying all of `Product`'s properties into `ProductChange` and making them all nullable works, but I really don't want to resort to doing that.**

In practice I will be using Change Tracking not just for products, but for dozens of entity types, which all have many properties. Having to specify each property in two places just to make Entity Framework play nice with Change Tracking is not a good idea.

Is there a way to get Keyless Entity Types to do what I want? Or do I have to use ADO.NET's `ExecuteReader` and manually map the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can use relationships with navigation properties on keyless entity types, just like you can with entity types.

Configure the relationship in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductChange>()
    .HasNoKey()
    .HasOne(x => x.Entity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductID) // I added this line.
    .ToView(null);
```

Now you can use `Include` instead of manually joining tables:

```
const string sql = "SELECT * FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbo.Product, {0}) AS CT";

var changes = await dbContext
    .Set<ProductChange>
    .FromSqlRaw(sql, lastSynchronizationVersion)
    .Include(x => x.Entity)
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // https://stackoverflow.com/a/63006304/1185136
    .ToArrayAsync();

// it works!
```

Additionally (this is optional), I created base types `Change` and `Change<TEntity>` that can be inherited from easily:

```
public abstract class Change
{
    public long Version { get; set; }
    public long? CreationVersion { get; set; }
    public char Operation { get; set; }
    public byte[]? Columns { get; set; }
    public byte[]? Context { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Change<TEntity> : Change
    where TEntity : class
{
    public TEntity? Entity { get; set; }
}
```

```
public ProductChange : Change<Product>
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
}

public OrderChange : Change<Order>
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
}

// etc...
```

You'll have to configure the relationship for each derived type in `OnModelCreating`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductChange>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Entity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductID);

modelBuilder.Entity<OrderChange>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Entity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderID);

// etc...
```

You won't have to repeat `HasNoKey()` and `ToView(null)` for every enitity though, add this loop instead:

```
foreach (var changeType in modelBuilder.Model.FindLeastDerivedEntityTypes(typeof(Change)))
{
    var builder = modelBuilder.Entity(changeType.ClrType).HasNoKey().ToView(null);

    builder.Property(nameof(Change.Version)).HasColumnName("SYS_CHANGE_VERSION");
    builder.Property(nameof(Change.CreationVersion)).HasColumnName("SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION");
    builder.Property(nameof(Change.Operation)).HasColumnName("SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION");
    builder.Property(nameof(Change.Columns)).HasColumnName("SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS");
    builder.Property(nameof(Change.Context)).HasColumnName("SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT");
}
```

If you want to, you can move the ID property to `Change<TEntity>`. By doing this, you can remove the `ProductChange`, `OrderChange` etc. classes. But, you'll have to specify the column name so Entity Framework Core understands the `ID` property from `Change<Product>` maps to `ProductID`, and the `ID` property from `Change<Order>` maps to `OrderID`, etc. I opted not to do this because this approach won't work if you have composite keys.