# how to join (A∩B') using left join in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, left-join

I want to df1 ∩ df2'   in a pandas dataframe

df1 has headers (given below) with 100 rows

```
  {a , b, c , d,x,y,v }
```

df2 has headers (given below) with 100 rows

```
{a, b, e, f,p,o,i}
```

the output of the join (just using the header names )

```
{c , d,x,y,v }
```

Comment: `df1.intersection(df2)`?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you told us what type `df1` and `df2` are. (I've got a guess, but it's one from a third-party library not among your tags)

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you mean by `df2'` ?

Comment: @jezrael, this is not intersection, but difference! - reopening.

Answer (score 2):

```
x1 =set(['a' , 'b', 'c' , 'd','x','y','v'])
x2 = set(['a', 'b', 'e', 'f','p','o','i'])
print(x1.difference(x2))
```

result would be:  `set(['y', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'v'])`

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a *left join* mean:

- All elements from `A` *(left)*
- plus all elements from `B` *(right)* that are in `A`

[Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/2889970), meaning in essence, the result is `A`?

If you want all elements of `A` that are not in `B`: `c = a - b`

If you want all elements that are in `A`and `B` *(intersection)*: `c = a & b`

Comment: {a , b, c , d,x,y,v } are the headers of df1. they a has some 100 rows. can i use 
x1.difference(x2)