# pyspark use dataframe inside udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes `df1`

```python
+---+---+----------+
|  n|val| distances|
+---+---+----------+
|  1|  1|0.27308652|
|  2|  1|0.24969208|
|  3|  1|0.21314497|
+---+---+----------+
```

and `df2`

```python
+---+---+----------+
| x1| x2|         w|
+---+---+----------+
|  1|  2|0.03103427|
|  1|  4|0.19012526|
|  1| 10|0.26805446|
|  1|  8|0.26825935|
+---+---+----------+
```

I want to add a new column to `df1` called `gamma`, which will contain the sum of the `w` value from `df2` when `df1.n == df2.x1 OR df1.n == df2.x2`

I tried to use udf, but apparently selecting from the different dataframe will not work, because values should be determined before calculation

```python
gamma_udf = udf(lambda n: float(df2.filter("x1 = %d OR x2 = %d"%(n,n)).groupBy().sum('w').rdd.map(lambda x: x).collect()[0]), FloatType())
df1.withColumn('gamma1', gamma_udf('n'))
```

Is there any way of doing it with `join` or `groupby` without using cycles?

Comment: `df1.join(df2, (df1.n == df2.x1) |  (df1.n == df2.x2)).groupBy(df1.n).sum("w")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference a DataFrame inside of a `udf`. As your alluded to, this problem is best solved using a `join`.

IIUC, you are looking for something like:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.alias("L").join(df2.alias("R"), (df1.n == df2.x1) | (df1.n == df2.x2), how="left")\
    .select("L.*", F.sum("w").over(Window.partitionBy("n")).alias("gamma"))\
    .distinct()\
    .show()
#+---+---+----------+----------+
#|  n|val| distances|     gamma|
#+---+---+----------+----------+
#|  1|  1|0.27308652|0.75747334|
#|  3|  1|0.21314497|      null|
#|  2|  1|0.24969208|0.03103427|
#+---+---+----------+----------+
```

Or if you're more comfortable with `pyspark-sql` syntax, you can register temp tables and do:

```python
df1.registerTempTable("df1")
df2.registerTempTable("df2")

sqlCtx.sql(
    "SELECT DISTINCT L.*, SUM(R.w) OVER (PARTITION BY L.n) AS gamma "
    "FROM df1 L LEFT JOIN df2 R ON L.n = R.x1 OR L.n = R.x2"
).show()
#+---+---+----------+----------+
#|  n|val| distances|     gamma|
#+---+---+----------+----------+
#|  1|  1|0.27308652|0.75747334|
#|  3|  1|0.21314497|      null|
#|  2|  1|0.24969208|0.03103427|
#+---+---+----------+----------+
```

**Explanation**

In both cases we are doing a [left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) of `df1` to `df2`. This will keep all the rows in `df1` regardless if there's a match.

The join clause is the condition that you specified in your question. So all rows in `df2` where either `x1` or `x2` equals `n` will be joined.

Next select all of the rows from the left tables plus we group by (partition by) `n` and sum the values of `w`. This will get the sum over all rows that matched the join condition, for each value of `n`.

Finally we only return distinct rows to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: What if the dimension of `df2` is much larger than `df1`, will the sum be taken through all values in `df2`?

Comment: The sum will be over all values in df2 that match the join condition over the partition by. Is this not working for you? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: I am not sure, a bit new in pyspark. I am just trying to figure out how your answer works.