# User Defined Function in withColumn called just once rather than per DF row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks

I have a problem with a user defined function built for concatenating values from one dataframe that matches index value from the other dataframe.

Here are the simplified dataframes that I am trying to match:

```sql
a_df:
+-------+------+
| index | name |
+-------+------+    
| 1     | aaa  |
| 2     | bbb  |
| 3     | ccc  |
| 4     | ddd  |
| 5     | eee  |
+-------+------+

b_df:
+-------+------+
| index | code |
+-------+------+    
| 1     | 101  |
| 2     | 102  |
| 3     | 101  |
| 3     | 102  |
| 4     | 103  |
| 4     | 104  |
| 5     | 101  |
+-------+------+
```

udf function & call:

```py
> def concatcodes(index, dataframe):
>   res = dataframe.where(dataframe.index == index).collect()
>   reslist = "|".join([value.code for value in res])
>   return reslist
> 
> spark.udf.register("concatcodes", concatcodes, StringType())
> 
> resultDF = a_DF.withColumn("codes", lit(concatcodes(a_DF.index, b_df)))
```

I expect the function to be called per each row of the a_DF dataframe, resulting in the following output:

```sql
+-------+------+-------+
| index | name |codes  |
+-------+------+-------+    
| 1     | aaa  |101    |
| 2     | bbb  |102    |
| 3     | ccc  |101|102|
| 4     | ddd  |103|104|
| 5     | eee  |101    |
+-------+------+-------+
```

However, the funtion seems to be called just once with the whole column passed as its argument, resulting in the following output:

```sql
+-------+------+---------------------------+
| index | name |codes                      |
+-------+------+---------------------------+    
| 1     | aaa  |101|102|101|102|103|104|101|    |
| 2     | bbb  |101|102|101|102|103|104|101|
| 3     | ccc  |101|102|101|102|103|104|101|
| 4     | ddd  |101|102|101|102|103|104|101|
| 5     | eee  |101|102|101|102|103|104|101|
+-------+------+---------------------------+
```

I suppose I am doing something fundamentally wrong when it comes to calling UDF in the .withColum method but I could not figure out what - I would very much appreciate someone pointing out what is wrong with my logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you [don't need a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296609/spark-functions-vs-udf-performance) for this. The heart of your question is essentially [Concatenating string by rows in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41788919/concatenating-string-by-rows-in-pyspark) and a `join`. The following will produce the desired output:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, concat_ws

resultDF = a_df.join(
    b_df.groupBy("index").agg(concat_ws("|", collect_list("code")).alias("code")), 
    on="index"
)

resultDF .show()
#+-----+----+-------+
#|index|name|   code|
#+-----+----+-------+
#|    3| ccc|101|102|
#|    5| eee|    101|
#|    1| aaa|    101|
#|    4| ddd|103|104|
#|    2| bbb|    102|
#+-----+----+-------+
```

Remember that spark DataFrames are inherently unordered, unless you explicitly introduce order with a `sort` or `orderBy`.

---

To address the issue with *your* attempt:

> I suppose I am doing something fundamentally wrong when it comes to calling UDF in the .withColum method but I could not figure out what

If you look at the execution plan for your code, you will see that the `where(dataframe.index == index)` portion is essentially being ignored.

```
resultDF = a_DF.withColumn("codes", lit(concatcodes(a_DF.index, b_df)))
resultDF.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Project [index#0, name#1, 101|102|101|102|103|104|101 AS codes#64]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[index#0,name#1]
```

My suspicion is that this is due to [the python `udf` being applied in batch mode, rather than on a `Row` basis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49634840/5858851). You can't [use a Dataframe inside a `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123238/pyspark-use-dataframe-inside-udf), so what must be happening is that the optimizer is running the `collect` once and using that for all rows.

The bigger issue here is that the approach of calling `collect` inside the `udf` defeats the purpose of spark (this is your fundamental misunderstanding). The whole point of using spark is to distribute your computations in parallel across multiple executors. When you use `collect` operations, this brings all the data into the local memory of the driver. (And in your case, it seems it's then broadcast back to the executors).

Instead, use `join`s when you need to reference data from multiple spark DataFrames. For `udf`s, you can think of them as essentially only being meant to operate on a single `Row` of a single spark DataFrame.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks for the spot on references and for touching on the broader context of what was wrong with my attempt - the suggested solution obviously works!

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach

`df = pd.merge(a_df,b_df, on = "index")`

```
df.groupby("index").agg({"name" : 'first', "code" : list})
```

The result is

```
index name        code

1      aaa       [101]
2      bbb       [102]
3      ccc  [101, 102]
4      ddd  [103, 104]
5      eee       [101]
```

Comment: This question is about spark dataframes, not `pandas` DataFrames

Comment: yes i know i did up-vote your answer(And it should be accepted as the answer too). I just put it here just in-case someone is looking for it.