# How does R interpret the joins ? from left to right or right to left

Tags: r, join, left-join, right-join

I have a disagreement with a colleague over the below two answers so need a third opinion.

Suppose you have 2 data frames: `Salary` and `Employee`.

Question: Which command would you use to join Employee and Salary by matching the rows from `Salary` to `Employee`?

```
Employee %>% left_join(Salary, by=c("F_NAME"="NAME"))
```

or

```
Employee %>% right_join(Salary, by=c("F_NAME"="NAME"))
```

Comment: Hi. You don't say what you want to accomplish in full detail so how can we know the answer? From your use of "join" in the text one would expect you want an inner join, not a (left or right) (or full?) outer join. Please read & act on [mcve]. But the answer to this question is trivially found, please don't ask unresearched or duplicate questions. See [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these commands will work, assuming that `Employee$F_NAME` and `Salary$NAME` contain matching items. The difference is in how rows that do not have matches are handled.

`left_join` will retain all rows in `Employee`. For rows that are in `Employee` but not `Salary`, any columns unique to `Salary` will be filled with `NA`.

`right_join` will retain all rows in `Salary`. For rows that are in `Salary` but not `Employee`, any columns unique to `Employee` will be filled with `NA`.

`inner_join` will retain only rows that are matched in both `Salary` and `Employee`. All others are dropped.

`full_join` will retain all rows from both data frames. Any rows that are not matched will have their missing left- or right-side columns filled with `NA`.

See also: [some very nice illustrations about join types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more specifically related to `dplyr` as opposed to the native R `merge`.  When you use

```
Employee %>% left_join(Salary, by=c("F_NAME"="NAME"))
```

you are concatenating the rows in `Employee` with all columns from `Employee` and `Salary`.  Missing values will be given `NA`.  Similarly,

```
Employee %>% right_join(Salary, by=c("F_NAME"="NAME"))
```

will yield all rows in `Salary` with all columns from both data frames.

I think your question may be more related to a `full_join`, but [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html#join-types) is a good place to get familiar with the methods.