# Join two tables to get both matching & unmatching rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Table scenario

TABLE1

```
TRAN_NO | SR_NO |MAT_NAME
---------------------------
001     |   1   |Material 1
001     |   2   |Material 2
```

TABLE2

```
TRAN_NO | SR_NO | TEMP
-------------------------
 001    |   1   | 10
 001    |   2   | 20
 001    |   3   | 30
 001    |   4   | 40
```

I want output like this

```
TRAN_NO | SR_NO |MAT_NAME    | TRAN_NO | SR_NO | TEMP
  001   |   1   | Material 1 |   001   |   1   |  10
  001   |   2   | Material 2 |   001   |   2   |  20
 NULL   | NULL  | NULL       |   001   |   3   |  30
 NULL   | NULL  | NULL       |   001   |   4   |  40
```

I tried all types of join including LEFT, RIGHT, CROSS but all of them either give matching rows or Cartesian product of them.

Comment: share here your queries you tried

Comment: Please try it yourself. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/5618563

Comment: Also; pay attention to the values in SR_NO in Table 2, you can never have an output like that with those values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: A `CROSS JOIN` would give you all combinations 2 x 4 = 8 rows. Not what you want. Don' use `RIGHT JOIN`, when you want to outer join a table. Right joins do the same thing as left joins, but are harder to read, because you must read the joins backwards. You want to outer join table1 to table2, so use a `LEFT JOIN`. Show what you tried. Where does your attempt fail? And where does SR_NO 4 come from? A typo?

Comment: Yes it was a type mistake..

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM 
TABLE1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.SR_NO = TABLE2.SR_NO This query worked..!

Comment: There is a TRAN_NO in both tables. Should it be used to join the tables as shown in krunal modi's answer? You should always provide sample data that includes edge cases. In your sample we see the same TRAN_NO / SR_NO pairs in both tables. What if SR_NO 2 had TRAN_NO 123 in table1? How would that change the results?

Comment: And as mentioned: Don't use `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`. Make it a Habit to use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` instead. (That is simply `table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON …` in your case.)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select *
from table1 a
right join table2 b on a.sr_no = b.sr_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

select a.*, b.*
from Table_2 b left join Table_1 a on a.TRAN_NO = b.TRAN_NO and a.sr_no = b.sr_no

Answer (score 0):

use left join like below

```
 select t1.*,t2.* from TABLE2 t2 left join TABLE1 t1 
 on t2.TRAN_NO=t1.TRAN_NO and t2.SR_NO=t1.SR_NO
```