# Using Outer joins in SQL

Tags: sql, outer-join

by analyzing the following **diagram**, I have to make a query to list all the products (**product**) and their associated category (**product_category**)
if they have one. Otherwise, display a value **(null)** for the category.

Display only the **PRODUCT_NAME** and **CATEGORY_NAME** columns in this order.

### Sample output:

| PRODUCT_NAME | CATEGORY_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| ProForm 6.0 RT | Fitness |
| Wilwood 260-11179 | Automotive |
| HC-SR04 | null |

---

[image]

So this is my query:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.name as PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_CATEGORY.name as CATEGORY_NAME
FROM PRODUCT 
   JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY ON PRODUCT.product_category_id = PRODUCT_CATEGORY.product_category_id
```

But I am not sure of my query, indeed I think I should use outer joins.

Comment: Right join instead of join

Comment: please also tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. You will need to use a **left outer join** to get the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT PRODUCT.name as PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_CATEGORY.name as CATEGORY_NAME
FROM PRODUCT LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_CATEGORY 
ON PRODUCT.product_category_id = PRODUCT_CATEGORY.product_category_id
```

The left outer join will return all records from the left hand table (PRODUCT). If there are no joined records from the right-hand table (PRODUCT_CATEGORY), then NULL will be returned for that all columns in that right-hand table for those records.

Comment: Thanks, but is left outer join the same than left join?

Comment: Yep, LEFT OUTER JOIN and LEFT JOIN are the same thing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server