# Ecto: How to access field of a preloaded association

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to get users who have no association with *friend_referral_code* or their code's status is false and they haven't used any code too. But I am unable to access the field *status* of the preloaded association *friend_referral_code*. Here is how I have done this:

```
def get_first_free_invite_users() do
    users =
      list_users()
      |> Repo.preload([:friend_referral_code])
      |> Enum.filter(
        fn u ->
          u.friend_referral_code == [] or u.friend_referral_code["status"] == false and
          Repo.all(from ref in FriendReferralCode,
            where: ref.receiver_id == ^u.id and ref.status == true) == []
        end)
    users
  end
```

It throws error on `u.friend_referral_code.status == false`. The reason I cannot go for join is that there might be no record of a particular user in FriendReferralCode and I want to capture those users. This is how the association is loaded:

```
friend_referral_code: [
      %MyApp.Accounts.FriendReferralCode{
        __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "friend_referral_code">,
        challenge: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :challenge is not loaded>,
        challenge_id: nil,
        code: "RFQTS",
        expiry: 1,
        id: 16021,
        inserted_at: ~N[2021-02-01 11:55:00],
        order: 1,
        prize: #Decimal<3>,
        receiver: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :receiver is not loaded>,
        receiver_id: 15002,
        state: "create_competition",
        status: false,
        updated_at: ~N[2021-02-01 11:57:20],
        user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
        user_id: 15001
      }
    ],
```

Comment: On one side um you compare `friend_referral_code` with a list and on the other you directly getting a field from a map?  How is this `friend_referral_code` mapped?

Comment: @EvaldoBratti I've added the association sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It throws error on u.friend_referral_code.status == false.

That's because `u.friend_referral_code` is a list in your example. You need to enumerate over `u.friend_referral_code` and check the status on each one.

Try something like this.

```
def get_ref_codes_by_user(id) do
  Repo.all(from ref in FriendReferralCode,
    where: ref.receiver_id == ^u.id and ref.status == true)
end

def filter_referrals([], user_id, acc), do: acc
def filter_referrals([ref, rest], user_id, acc) do
  is_used = 
    ref == [] || ref.status == false && get_ref_codes_by_user(id) == []
  
  new_acc = 
    case is_used do
      true -> acc
      false -> [ref | acc]
    end

  filter_referrals(rest, user_id, new_acc)
end

def get_first_free_invite_users() do
  list_users()
  |> Repo.preload([:friend_referral_code])
  |> Enum.map(
    fn u ->
      filter_referrals(u.friend_referral_code, u.id, [])
    end)
end
```

This will get you a lot closer and give you a list of list of `FriendReferralCode`s. Double check that the logic is what you want here. All that said, you should be able to do this with a join. Check the docs [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5) and this other SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/1521117) about join types.

Try

```
Repo.all(from ref in FriendReferralCode,
  right_join users u on ref.user_id =  u.id
    where: ref.status == true)
```

Comment: Oh yes! I was somehow overlooking the fact that it is list. Your answer is awesome

Comment: Happy to help! Do play around with Ecto though, its super powerful.