# SQL from a column of a query to row of another query

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I am looking for a method that extracts the dates of Result 2, add
to be columns of Result 1, final as Expect result.

After Googled, I tried to use transform but mess result. How could
I build the result? Thanks.

Result 1:

| merchantRef | totalAmount | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | UK |
| 2 | 20 | UK |
| 3 | 60 | UK |

```
SELECT tblThree.merchantRef, tblThree.inDate
FROM tblThree;
```

Result 2 (tblThree):

| merchantRef | inDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/21/2010 |
| 2 | 02/28/2021 |
| 3 | 06/15/2021 |
| 3 | 07/15/2021 |

Expect result:

| merchantRef | totalAmount | country | inDate | inDate2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | UK | 12/21/2010 |  |
| 2 | 20 | UK | 02/28/2021 |  |
| 3 | 60 | UK | 06/15/2021 | 07/15/2021 |

Comment: Why are you only taking indates for merchant 3?

Comment: thanks, the inDates is coming from another table. Like, for example, transaction dates of a merchanRef

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: thanks, tried but SQL join cannot transpose inDate in Result 2 to columns in Expect result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lateral join -- which is like a subquery that can return multiple rows:

```
select t1.*, t3.*
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select nullif(min(t3.indate), max(t3.indate)) as indate1,
             nullif(max(t3.indate), min(t3.indate)) as indate2
      from table3 t3
      where t3.merchantRef = t1.merchantRef
     ) t3;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will try later. And may I have your comment that what if more than two inDates with same merchanRef ? thanks

Comment: @NormanCF . . . This question is specifically about returning two columns of values.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: @ Gordon... thanks for remind. Sorry about that I made an unclear question. I think I will edit again this question  since infact, the result 2 have not only 2 similar merchantRef.