# SQL Select missing and updated rows only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

**The Problem**: How can I combine two SQL conditions for matching/joining into one statement? I want both missing records, but also if the record I have is outdated, I want to grab the latest and greatest. I have done with two separate SQL queries and then used a `UNION` on the `DISTINCT` `Id`'s but I would prefer to combine this into one query if possible. I'm struggling with the approach so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**Source Table**

| id | modified_at |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2023-10-02 16:42 |
| b | 2023-10-03 16:42 |
| c | 2023-10-04 16:42 |
| d | 2023-10-05 16:42 |
| e | 2023-10-06 16:42 |
| f | 2023-10-07 16:42 |
| g | 2023-10-08 16:42 |
| h | 2023-10-09 16:42 |
| i | 2023-10-10 16:32 |
| j | 2023-10-11 16:52 |

**Destination Table**

| id | modified_at |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2023-10-02 16:42 |
| b | 2023-10-03 16:42 |
| c | 2023-10-04 16:42 |
| d | 2023-10-05 16:42 |
| h | 2023-10-09 16:42 |
| i | 2023-10-10 16:32 |
| j | 2023-09-11 16:52 |

**Desired Result from SELECT**

| id | modified_at |
| --- | --- |
| e | 2023-10-06 16:42 |
| f | 2023-10-07 16:42 |
| g | 2023-10-08 16:42 |
| j | 2023-10-11 16:52 |

**Rationale:** `e`, `f`, and `g` are missing records in `destination`, so we want to include them in our result set. Last but not least `j` is included because `source` has a more recent record than `destination` due to the `modified_at` timestamp, so we want to include it to get the latest and greatest. My current attempts are below:

**Technical Limitation**: Not able to use transactions, if statements, loops, inserts, or updates. I'm strictly limited to select statements, joins, crosses, etc..

**SQL: All records that changed**

```
SELECT
  id,
  modified_at
FROM source
WHERE source.modified_at >= (SELECT MAX(modified_at) AS last_modified_at FROM destination)
```

**SQL: All missing records**

```
SELECT
  source.id,
  source.modified_at
FROM source
LEFT JOIN destination
  ON source.Id = destination.id
WHERE destination.id IS NULL
```

Comment: _" Not able to use transactions, if statements, loops, inserts, or updates. I'm strictly limited to select statements, joins, crosses, etc.."_ - (not that you'd need to use them, but it would help if you explained why you're restricted like this...)

Comment: Seems you just need a logical `OR` between the 2 conditions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a `UNION` operator - **this is a good situation to use it** - it's still a single query as far as the SQL engine is concerned.

Comment: @DaleK I guess it's just been a really long day that I spaced and made it a lot more complex in my head than it needed to be lol. I'll mark it as answered when I can, thank you.

Comment: @Dai limitation of the software I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

When asking questions like this it's helpful to provide the DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @SourceTable TABLE (ID VARCHAR(1), ModifiedDateTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @SourceTable (ID, ModifiedDateTime) VALUES
('a', '2023-10-02 16:42'), ('b', '2023-10-03 16:42'), ('c', '2023-10-04 16:42'), ('d', '2023-10-05 16:42'), 
('e', '2023-10-06 16:42'), ('f', '2023-10-07 16:42'), ('g', '2023-10-08 16:42'), ('h', '2023-10-09 16:42'), 
('i', '2023-10-10 16:32'), ('j', '2023-10-11 16:52');

DECLARE @DestinationTable TABLE (ID VARCHAR(1), ModifiedDateTime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @DestinationTable (ID, ModifiedDateTime) VALUES
('a', '2023-10-02 16:42'), ('b', '2023-10-03 16:42'), ('c', '2023-10-04 16:42'), ('d', '2023-10-05 16:42'), 
('h', '2023-10-09 16:42'), 
('i', '2023-10-10 16:32'), ('j', '2023-09-11 16:52');
```

As @Dai suggests, you can either use an `OR` or a `UNION ALL` here:

```
/* OR */
SELECT *
  FROM @SourceTable s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DestinationTable d
      ON s.ID = d.ID
 WHERE d.ID IS NULL
    OR s.ModifiedDateTime > d.ModifiedDateTime;

/* UNION ALL */
SELECT *
  FROM @SourceTable s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DestinationTable d
      ON s.ID = d.ID
 WHERE d.ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM @SourceTable s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DestinationTable d
      ON s.ID = d.ID
 WHERE s.ModifiedDateTime > d.ModifiedDateTime;
```

| ID | ModifiedDateTime | ID | ModifiedDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e | 2023-10-06 16:42:00.000 |  |  |
| f | 2023-10-07 16:42:00.000 |  |  |
| g | 2023-10-08 16:42:00.000 |  |  |
| j | 2023-10-11 16:52:00.000 | j | 2023-09-11 16:52:00.000 |

Comment: Why `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @JordanGS You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) but they actually the same thing, it just depends on what you find more clear to read

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a simple OR:

```sql
SELECT
  source.id,
  source.modified_at
FROM source
LEFT JOIN destination
  ON source.Id = destination.id
WHERE (
    destination.id IS NULL
 OR source.modified_at >= destination.modified_at
)
```

Your code does some sort of MAX so they're not completely equavalent, but i think the above is the canonical version of missing / new changes